# PoolProcessExecutor and Subprocess Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, subprocess, python-asyncio

### Problem

I am attempting to generate a client server asynchronous communication. In other terms I have a batch file running with a client that handles runs and communicates to the client. I am using `PoolProcessExecutor` to call the client and the batch process. The process will stop running after spinning up the client.

The code looks something like the following:

###### BatchFile:

```
 def subprocess_function():
        p = Popen(scriptPath, cwd=filepath)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

###### Driver File

```
for episode in range(n_episodes):
    print(f"\r\n{'-' * 60}\r\n")
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        client = CustomClient("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556", "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
        sub_proc = executor.submit(subprocess_function)
        client_proc = executor.submit(client.Start(agent, buffer))
```

#### Question

When I try to turn the subprocess_function into class where I assign the process to a variable, I believe it causes the code to await to be assigned before moves on to spinning up the next process but I am not 100% sure.

Do I need to use `ThreadPoolProcessor` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `ProcessPoolExecutor` blocks when you leave the `with` block for the submitted work to finish.  You need to commute your `with` and `for` blocks.  Also it appears you're calling `client.Start` in your main thread which is likely an issue as well.  Instead you just want to pass that method along with it's arguments to the subprocess.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for episode in range(n_episodes):
        print(f"\r\n{'-' * 60}\r\n")
        client = CustomClient("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556", "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
        sub_proc = executor.submit(subprocess_function)
        client_proc = executor.submit(client.Start, agent, buffer)
```

See the documentation on the [`Executor.shutdown` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) which is called at the end of the `with` block.

Comment: What if if were to attempt to create a class instead of a functions, so now subprocess_function is now a method ie it is called by doing class = SubProc.start(). This seems to cause it to become hung up, would I declare the class before the `with` and the `for` loop?

Comment: Are you saying your issue is the line `executor.submit(client.Start(agent, buffer))`?  If so the problem is that you don't want to _call_ client start as an argument for `submit`, you just want to submit it.  You probably want `executor.submit(client.Start, agent, buffer)`.  Here we avoid calling `client.Start` in the main process.  We just pass the function and the arguments to the subprocess and the subprocess calls the function.